# Opcache Preloading with Symfony 5.4 / PHP8 / Platform.sh

Tags: php, symfony, opcache, platform.sh

I am attempting to set up Opcache Preloading on Symfony 5.4 running on PHP8 at Platform.sh, and running into a fatal error.

**Configuration**

Necessary pieces included:

```
// platform.app.yaml
...
variables
  php
    'opcache.preload': 'var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.php'
...

hooks:
  build: |
    ...
    composer dump-autoload --no-dev --classmap-authoritative
  deploy: |
    ...
    sv restart app
...
```

I can verify that the `App_KernelProdContainer.php` file is being created at the correct location defined in the config above:

```
<?php

// This file has been auto-generated by the Symfony Dependency Injection Component for internal use.

if (\class_exists(\ContainerF9HiXre\App_KernelProdContainer::class, false)) {
    // no-op
} elseif (!include __DIR__.'/ContainerF9HiXre/App_KernelProdContainer.php') {
    touch(__DIR__.'/ContainerF9HiXre.legacy');

    return;
}

if (!\class_exists(App_KernelProdContainer::class, false)) {
    \class_alias(\ContainerF9HiXre\App_KernelProdContainer::class, App_KernelProdContainer::class, false);
}

return new \ContainerF9HiXre\App_KernelProdContainer([
    'container.build_hash' => 'F9HiXre',
    'container.build_id' => '98091d49',
    'container.build_time' => 1644501054,
], __DIR__.\DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'ContainerF9HiXre');
```

The included file `ContainerF9HiXre/App_KernelProdContainer.php` throws errors on the use statements like this:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class &quot;Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container&quot; not found in /app/var/cache/prod/ContainerF9HiXre/App_KernelProdContainer.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /app/var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.php(7): include()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /app/var/cache/prod/ContainerF9HiXre/App_KernelProdContainer.php on line 17
```

Use statements in the included file appear as such:

```
namespace ContainerF9HiXre;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Argument\RewindableGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\LogicException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\RuntimeException;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\FrozenParameterBag;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using the wrong file for preloading.

The generated file is named something like `srcApp_KernelProdContainer.preload.php`. But in any case, you probably should't be adding this file directly to `opcache.preload`, but the Symfony generated `config/preload.php`.

Since on platform.sh [the path is resolved relative to the project root](https://docs.platform.sh/languages/php.html#opcache-preloading), you can use a relative path like this:

```
opcache.preload=config/preload.php
```

If you do not have this file (e.g. incomplete recipes), you could simply re-generate it by running `composer recipes:update symfony/framework-bundle`, as explained [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/performance.html#use-the-opcache-class-preloading).

Or, ir you are not using Symfony Flex and want to do it manually, you can simply copy the file from the appropriate recipe, [like this one](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/5.4/config/preload.php).

It's a very simple script in any case:

```
<?php

if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php')) {
    require dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php';
}
```

Comment: Thank you! that certainly was the issue. However now I have different problems. Perhaps this merits a new question...`<b>Warning</b>:  Can't preload already declared class Google_AccessToken_Revoke in <b>/app/vendor/google/apiclient/src/aliases.php</b> on line <b>45</b><br />
[10-Feb-2022 15:05:18 UTC] PHP Warning:  Can't preload unlinked class Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\ExpressionLanguage: Unknown parent Symfony\Component\ExpressionLanguage\ExpressionLanguage in /app/vendor/symfony/security-core/Authorization/ExpressionLanguage.php on line 30`

Comment: It is, indeed, a separate issue. I feel like this question has been adequately answered. The preloading problems with these specific classes should be investigated on their own. I use preloading myself, and have no issues.